# selecting different rows with same value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

First off, this is a bit difficult to explain but i will try my best as I cannot figure this out!

I'm trying to create an affiliate system using php and mysql.

the affiliate system will give each person a unique ID like so: T1, T2, T3, T4 etc etc...

each affiliate account can invite sellers and and buyers into the site.

some affiliates will invite both sellers and buyers to the site.

when an order is placed on the system, the mysql database table (called orders) will have a new data with all the details inserted into it.

there are two different columns in the orders table.

```
buyers_REF
Sellers_REF
```

the structure of them is like so:

```
buyer_REF    Sellers_REF
T1               T1
T1
                 T1
T2               T1
T3               T2
```

I am using the `$GET` to get the value from the URL like so: `mypage.php?id=T1` and then select everything in both columns mentioned above if its found.

the issue that I have is that I cannot get all the results from mysql for some reason and I cannot figure out the correct way of doing this.

basically, I need to $GET the URLvalue and search the mysql database and find all the matched ones.

example:

`mypage.php?id=T1` should give me the result for 5 `T1` according to my example above but i only get 3 or sometimes 2 and I don't understand the logic behind this mismatching.

This is what I have done:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$targetID = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE buyer_REF='$targetID' OR Sellers_REF='$targetID'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

///////Rest Of My Code Goes Here/////////

}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: First off, for your references, I would use MySQLs `AUTO INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY` to generate this id for you.  It seems like you are creating your own `T1`, `T2`, etc.  Secondly, you should be using `PREPARED STATEMENTS` for your queries so you aren't vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: In expecting 5 `T1` results, does that mean you want to have the first row show up twice because both `buyer_ref` and `sellers_ref` are equal to `T1`?

Comment: @Dan, i will use prepared statements and yes I am creating the numbers myself but I also use auto increment for ids of each order. this T1, T2, T3 etc is for affiliates and that's their reference number.. nothing to do with the id's of orders.

Comment: @EdGibbs, yes, correct.

Comment: @william, I might be missing something, but why do you need two columns in the same table to denote the same thing then?

Comment: @Dan, because some buyers will spend more hours on the site than sellers or vice versa... so at the end I need to calculate the hours for each user and split that between the referrer and the person whose been referred. and the only way to link these two types of users is by giving them these T1, T2 ref numbers and in the end do the calculations based on the hours spent... I know it might be a bit confusing BUT that is how i need to do it.

Comment: william, a `UNION ALL` will do this: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE buyer_REF = # UNION ALL SELECT * FROM orders WHERE Sellers_REF = #`, where # is the `$targetID` placed safely in the query by way of prepared statements as @Dan rightly suggests :) Also, note that returning duplicate rows like this is often questionable, but for all I know it's perfectly reasonable for your requirements.

Comment: @william, do you have a users table to hold buyers and sellers?

Comment: @Dan, yes.. ofcourse.

Comment: @william, not to get too into it, but I suppose I'm suggesting that you should be using the user table ID as the reference, and you should use an auto incrememnting ID for that reference, not your T1, T2 keys...

Comment: @EdGibbs, that did it mate. Thanks.. I think doing it this way UNION ALL is much better than having so many join table functions.